# Sentence Parser - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I decided to repost, after some formatting complaints on my previous submission.

The program, should parse the list [a,command,moving,to,a,higher,directory] into:

det(a),noun(command),verb(moving),prep(to),det(a),adj(higher),noun(directory).

However the program fails after trying to assign a det(to), when instead it should go through and assign to as a prepositional phrase (prep).

This is definitely a backtracking issue, but can anyone spot whats wrong with my code?

Program:

```
/* Facts */
det(the).
det(a).
det(more).

prep(in).
prep(to).

noun(detail).
noun(command).
noun(directory).
noun(file).
noun('08226txt').

adj(moving).
adj(parent).
adj(current).
adj(fine).
adj(higher).
adj(short).
adj(very).

verb(moves).
verb(print).
verb(types).
verb(viewed).
verb(listing).
verb(moving).


/* S -> NP VP
   S -> VP */
sentence(Sentence,sentence(np(Noun_Phrase),vp(Verb_Phrase))):-
  np(Sentence,Noun_Phrase,Rem),
  vp(Rem,Verb_Phrase).

/* NP -> Det NP2
   NP -> NP2
   NP -> NP PP */
np([X|T],np(det(X),NP2),Rem):-
  det(X),
  np2(T,NP2,Rem).
np(Sentence,Parse,Rem):- np2(Sentence,Parse,Rem).
np(Sentence,np(NP,PP),Rem):-
  np(Sentence,NP,Rem1),
  pp(Rem1,PP,Rem).

/* NP2 -> Noun
   NP2 -> Adj NP2 */
np2([H|T],np2(noun(H)),T):- noun(H).
np2([H|T],np2(adj(H),Rest),Rem):-
      adj(H),
      np2(T,Rest,Rem).

/* PP -> Prep NP */
pp([H|T],pp(prep(H),Parse),Rem):-
  prep(H),
  np(T,Parse,Rem).

/* VP -> Verb
   VP -> Verb NP
   VP -> VP PP */
vp([H|[]],verb(H)):-
  verb(H).
vp([H|Rest],vp(verb(H),RestParsed)):-
  verb(H),
  np(Rest,RestParsed,_).
vp([H|Rest],vp(verb(H),RestParsed)):-
  vp(H,Rest),
  pp(Rest,RestParsed,_).
```

Program output with trace:[Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO5A9.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be easier to write this parser using [definite clause grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar).

Comment: I would, however, this parser is meant to hold a vast range of values for my coursework, and so it has been specified to do it this way.

Comment: I looked at a more complete trace (ran the code) and looked at your `np` predicate definition. It showed that the code goes into a loop. I think the trouble may be here: `np(Sentence,np(NP,PP),Rem):-
  np(Sentence,NP,Rem1),
  pp(Rem1,PP,Rem).` This recursive call is probably circular and it never gets a chance to check `pp`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and look into my problem, that was indeed the problem, and managed to find it before looking on here, so sorry for wasting your time! Thanks again though:)

Comment: Not a waste of time! I'm glad you were able to figure it out.